# I was wondering how to bind a sentence to the CAPS_LOCK key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, bind

I want to use my <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> to bind a word to a key (more specifically to bind it to `require 2htdp/image`).